# Find Numbers with Dot only from String

Tags: c#, regex

How can i find numeric number with dot only from string e.g in below string

```
1. A traveller is thirsty in a desert at 15° E and 25° S. The desert in question is  (a) Kalahari (b) Patagonia (c) Sahara (d) Mohave 2. The Kalahari Desert, which stretches over 225,000 miles (900,000 sq. m), is in (a) Australia (b) (c) East Africa (d)
```

I want to find 1. and 2. and append

before i have tried

```
string result = Regex.Replace(source, "\\d+", $"$0<br />");
```

but it returns all numeric numbers from string. Thank u.

Comment: the dot is missing `\\d+\\.` in your RegEx https://regex101.com/r/ORy7EK/1

Comment: but how would i append <br/> before..

Comment: `$0` is your match - so you have to replace `"$0<br />"` with `"<br />$0"`

Comment: It worked @fubo. U r Awsom

Answer (score 2):

Answered in the comments above, @fubo

> How to insert break `<br/>` before digit with dot  `1.` and `2.`

```
var s = "1. A traveller is thirsty in a desert at 15° E [...] 2. The Kalahari Desert, [...]";

var result = Regex.Replace(s, "\\d+\\.", "<br/>$0");
```